# Why does blood turn reddish brown?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, color

Why does blood take on such a colour after a couple of hours?

[image: blood]

Is this the iron in my blood being oxidised to iron (III) oxide or is this something else?

I have checked [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15187/why-does-blood-get-further-oxidized-than-iron-oxide) article, and no I do not find a definite answer to my question. I want to learn about the chemistry behind this change in colour of blood from bright red to brown. *thanks*

Comment: "As red blood cells degrade within a bruise, haemoglobin breaks down into bilirubin and biliverdin, and it is these pigments that pass through a series of colour changes. " https://www.quora.com/Why-does-a-blood-clot-change-colour